# Matplotlib Time-Series Heatmap Visualization Row Modification

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, matplotlib

Thank you in advance for the assistance!

I am trying to create a heat map from time-series data and the data begins mid year, which is causing the top of my heat map to be shifted to the left and not match up with the rest of the plot (Shown Below). How would I go about shifting the just the top line over so that the visualization of the data syncs up with the rest of the plot?

(Code Provided Below)

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# links to datadata
url1 = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/the-datadudes/deepSoilTemperature/master/minotDailyAirTemp.csv'

# load the data into a DataFrame, not a Series
# parse the dates, and set them as the index
df1 = pd.read_csv(url1, parse_dates=['Date'], index_col=['Date'])

# groupby year and aggregate Temp into a list
dfg1 = df1.groupby(df1.index.year).agg({'Temp': list})

# create a wide format dataframe with all the temp data expanded
df1_wide = pd.DataFrame(dfg1.Temp.tolist(), index=dfg1.index)

# ploting the data

fig, (ax1) = plt.subplots(ncols=1, figsize=(20, 5))


ax1.matshow(df1_wide, interpolation=None, aspect='auto');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now, what its the problem, the dates on the dataset, if you see the Dataset this start on

```
`1990-4-24,15.533`
```

To solve this is neccesary to add the data between 1990/01/01 -/04/23 and delete the 29Feb.

```
rng = pd.date_range(start='1990-01-01', end='1990-04-23', freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame(index= rng)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df['Temp'] = np.NaN
frames = [df, df1]
result = pd.concat(frames)
result = result[~((result.index.month == 2) & (result.index.day == 29))]
```

With this data

```
dfg1 = result.groupby(result.index.year).agg({'Temp': list})
df1_wide = pd.DataFrame(dfg1['Temp'].tolist(), index=dfg1.index)

# ploting the data

fig, (ax1) = plt.subplots(ncols=1, figsize=(20, 5))


ax1.matshow(df1_wide, interpolation=None, aspect='auto');
```

[image]

The problem with the unfilled portions are a consequence of the NaN values on your dataset, in this case you take the option, replace the NaN values with the column-mean or replace by the row-mean.
Another ways are available to replace the NaN values

```
df1_wide = df1_wide.apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()),axis=0)
```

[image]

Comment: I understand that you are averaging the rest of the data on the plot, but the top line is still out of sync for everything left of the 250 mark. How would I move it over to the right and fill in the blank space that will appear to the left?  I have also updated the image in the original question in order to make what I am asking more obvious